# How to send multiple mails for different recipients using delayed jobs in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I am trying to send multiple mails for different recipients at a time i have implemented delayed jobs but until i run this command `rake jobs:work` i won't get the mails.

I have this code in `mailers/user_mailer.rb`:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email(email)
    #@recipient_name = name  
    mail(to: email, subject: 'Hello: New jobs posted matching your skills')
  end
end
```

And in my controller i have this code:

```
def create
  @recipients = User.all
  respond_to do |format|
    if @job.save
      @recipients.each do |recipient|
        UserMailer.delay.welcome_email(recipient.email)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And how to send for all recipients the user's who is signed.

Comment: You would typically start a background process, see [Running Jobs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#running-jobs).

Comment: The *whole point* of background jobs (sidekiq, delayed_job, resque, ...) is that they are not handled by the main server. Instead, they are handled by a separate process. In order to have the emails sent automatically, you need to run that separate process.